# Actionscript 3, walk cycle loop during tween motion

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I have a MC character, inside of it there's a walk cycle frame by frame animation

My character move on the stage with a tween (used tweenLite from GreenSock) wherever you click with the mouse.

I want the walk cycle loops till the end of the tween, actually it iterates only one time, any advice?

Comment: If you don't have a stop() on the last frame (or in a script), it will continue to loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TweenLite, you can its onComplete callback to repeat your tween.
e.g.

```
TweenLite.to(mc, { onComplete: function(tweenliteInstance):void{
    tweenLiteInstance.play();}, 
    onCompleteParams : ["{self}"] }
);
```